# SQL-Query in PHPmyadmin can't differentiate Emojis

Tags: sql, unicode, mariadb

I've googled and found nothing so far 'cause the most problems with this seems to relate to the character set, which seems to be correct in my case.

**Situation:**
I want to count People with different Emojis in their name but it seems to be that the query can't differentiate between Emojis.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN u.nick LIKE '%%'
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) AS 'NF'
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN u.nick LIKE '%%'
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) AS 'T'
FROM users u

--> 

|NF |T  |               |NF|T |
---------   Should be:  -------
|128|128|               |76|52|
```

The following Query will Result in a list of anybody who has a unicode-sign in his name and not only those with the -Emoji. This supports my thesis, that the Query doesn't want to differentiate between any unicode-signs.

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE u.nick LIKE '%%'
```

**Additional Information:**
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server-Typ: MariaDB
Server-Version: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04
Protokoll-Version: 10
Server-Zeichensatz: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.22
PHP-Erweiterung: mysqli Dokumentation curl Dokumentation mbstring Dokumentation
PHP-Version: 7.4.22
Table "user" Kollation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Row nick-Typ: varchar(255)
Row nick-Kollation: utf8mb4_general_ci

Does anybody has a clue where the problem could be?

Comment: This doesn't sound phpMyAdmin related. Have you tried with a different client, e.g. CLI?

Comment: phpMyAdmin seems to behave correct, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whnew.png

Comment: and even [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0497892aaf03613617e9e13e88006dce) seems to work OK.   Can you create a [mre] ?  (currently it is unclear how the table `users` is defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that this is caused by [the Sushi-Beer problem](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76553) which treats all emojis as equal. If you want to uniquely identify each character, you can use the `utf8mb4_bin` collation:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT '' = '';
+-----------+
| '?' = '?' |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT '' = '';
+-----------+
| '?' = '?' |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: THX!

I read up on the problem you mentioned and changed the collation to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" and that fixed it entirely!